# tun0 interface (created by opevpn) only useable as root

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, permissions, openvpn

If I do `curl ipinfo.io --interface tun0`, it will hang forever. but if I do `sudo curl ipinfo.io --interface tun0`, it will work as expected. How can i make tun0 useable by non root users?

tun0 is created by openvpn

Comment: There are a lot of possible changes between the two commands: eg: sudo loses environment variables (http_proxy ?) then if you have firewall rules or even routing rules that check the owner ... not enough information from the question to guess